# From Static Change to Live Change

Tags: javascript, live

I have a Javascript code that I'm using to change the appearance of certain elements based on the time of day.

My question is: Is there a way to for these appearance changes to be viewable "live" while on the page, without requiring a person to reload/refresh the web page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDayTime(hours) {
if (hours > 20 || hours < 5)
return "night";

if (hours > 17)
return "dusk";

if (hours > 8)
return "day";

return "dawn";
}

$(function() {
document.body.className = getDayTime(new Date().getHours());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval()` to update the value every `x` milliseconds. For example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.body.className = getDayTime(new Date().getHours());
}, 1000); // update every second
```